# Realm object server - run function only once

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

And after that I have to restart object server (latest version 1.8.2), and then again - only once... in log files there is only one related error: 
`functions: Child process exited with exit code 99`
In syslog there is only

```
Aug  3 17:45:10 little realm-object-server[2398]: read configuration from /etc/realm/configuration.yml.
Aug  3 17:45:12 little realm-object-server[2398]: result: [object Object]
```

Comment: This question appears incomplete — can you update with more information please? :-)

Comment: What information do You need? In log files there is nothing except this 2 lines ...

Comment: I was referring to your description. I'm not sure I understand exactly what it is you are trying to achieve or what indication you are getting that it doesn't work.

Comment: I have installed Realm Object Server 1.8.2, it has Functions that run when record is changed, so when I create/change realm record this function works, but if I create/change one more record - it doest not (i'v been testing it many times, even create request to other server to see if it works fine, but not displaying in console). I can only stop function, and then I can't start it again - in log appears "functions: Child process exited with exit code 99". I'v tried to uninstall/install Realm Server but that does not help